# comparing two list with custom objects, not behaving as I expect (Lexicography comparison) - Python

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have two Python lists.

```
a = [A(1), B(1)]
b = [A(1), B(2)]
```

The check `a < b` does not get to call B's `__lt__` operator. The conclusion is that *a* is not smaller than *b*.
I have verified that A's `__lt__` is called (actually twice to see if the first element in *a* is smaller than the one in *b*, and then the other way around).

Thanks in advance,

Oren

Comment: is this python 2.7 or python 3.x ?

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: the only thing that is still bothering me is the fact that you say it gets called twice, this should never happen, so i think this might be an issue somewhere else in the calling code. my small reproductions did not have the double call problem

Comment: @miThom you are probably right, and it is being called only one. The other call came from another source in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare two lists in Python, it compares them element-by-element and stops comparing them after finding two unequal elements. This doesn't mean that one element has to be greater or less than the other, just that they have to be unequal. Here's a naive example using something that I think is similar to what you have; consider a `class A`:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self, obj):
        return self.val < obj.val
```

Now consider two objects `a` and `b` such that `a = A(1)` and `b = A(1)`. `a < b` evaluates to `False` like we'd expect, but `a == b` also evaluates to `False`. This is because the object has no way to compare equality through an `__eq__` method, and the objects are not the exact same instance. We can add one like so:

```
def __eq__(self, obj):
    return self.val == obj.val
```

Now, `a == b` will evaluate to `True` and your original expression will work as expected.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, I'll implement also `__eq__`

Answer (score 1):

Python will only compare the second items if the first items were found to be equal. If the second items are not being compared this implies the first items were not equal.

So the issue likely lies with the `__lt__` implementation for A, if you want to post that code we might be able to help spot the issue.

Comment: this is not completely correct, python does not see the first elements as the same since it are different objects (different reference), this will cause __lt__ to be called on the first object only once

Comment: This is "A": `class EMIDCandidate(Candidate):
    def __init__(self, keyword, count):
        super(EMIDCandidate, self).__init__(keyword)
        self.count = count
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"EMID: {self.keyword} x {self.count}"
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print("!", self, other)
        return self.count < other.count`

Answer (score 1):

[the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__) clearly states that **lt** gets called on the first object that is not equal. In your example you did not mention you inplemented the **eq** operator, so this is my reproduction:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        print('lt in A')
        return self.val < other.val

class B:
     def __init__(self, val):
         self.val = val
    def __lt__(self, other):
         print('lt in B')
         return self.val < other.val

a = [A(1), B(2)]
b = [A(1), B(1)]

print(a < b)
```

which outputs:

```
lt in A
False
```

because  the first object is different (although the same val) and it will take the result of that **lt**

---

when you implement the `__eq__` method, it will continue to do this:
    class A:
        def **init**(self, val):
            self.val = val

```
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print('lt in A')
        return self.val < other.val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val
```

will output

```
lt in B
True
```

because the first element evaluates to true using **eq**